# Как сделать значения из двух массивов значениями объекта JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива

```
const color = ["#75ACF0", "#7191F2", "#195EE6"];
const number = [100, 20, 50, 140]
```

В массиве `number` может быть и 1 значение и 10, и 3, нет фиксированного числа значений. И если количество этих значений больше количества цветов, то они должны брать по порядку из `color` значения

и нужно сделать так, чтобы получился объект, с заданными ключами, чтобы он брал значения из массивов для него.
Т.е. должен быть объект

```
{ 
  value: number[i],
  item: {
    color: color[i],
  },
}
```

Comment: На выходе должен получится массив объектов? Можете привести пример вывода этой функции для аргументов, которые вы указали:
`const color = ["#75ACF0", "#7191F2", "#195EE6"];`
`const number = [100, 20, 50, 140];`

Comment: В итоге должно получиться, что-то такое

data: [
  {
    value: 100,
    item: {
      color: "#75ACF0",
  },
  {
    value: 20,
    item: {
      color: "#7191F2",
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    item: {
      color: "#75ACF0",
  },
  {
    value: 140,
    item: {
      color: "#75ACF0",
  },
],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень плохое объяснение того, что Вам надо.

```js
const color = ["#75ACF0", "#7191F2", "#195EE6"];
const number = [100, 20, 50, 140];

const result = number.map((n, i) => ({
  value: n,
  item: {
    color: color[i % color.length],
  }
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это очень похоже на то, что нужно в итоге

Comment: @zybpa Это не похоже, а именно то.